# HLSL error X4507: maximum constant register index exceeded

Tags: directx, direct3d, hlsl, vertex-shader

I have a vertex shader with a cbuffer that contains this member:

```
float4 myArray[16];
```

In the body of the shader I can read and use the array values using a variable index:

```
float4 anElement = myArray[(int)(input.Color.g * 255)];
```

This compiles fine. However, if I declare the array as having 256 elements:

```
float4 myArray[256];
```

Then the compiler fails with the following error:

> error X4507: maximum vs_4_0_level_9_1 constant register index (256)
>   exceeded - Try reducing number of constants referenced   compilation
>   failed; no code produced

This error doesn't occur if I use a constant index into myArray. MSDN doesn't have documentation on error 4507. Is it possible for me to dynamically index an array that is greater that 255 elements long? Is this a DirectX9 cap?

I'm using shader model 4.0 level 9_1.

Comment: What do you mean with static index? Have you tried casting the float to int?

Comment: By static indexer I meant a constant one. Yes, I tried explicitly casting (e.g. myArray[(int)(input.Color.g * 255)];).

Comment: It seems that the compiler creates some more constant values in the dynamic case (I didn't have a look at the compiled code though). If you specify `float4 myArray[254]`, it works. You can split the array into two as a workaround for now.

Comment: @NicoSchertler if you want to put your comment into an answer I'll gladly mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rather a workaround than a solution. You can split the array into two (or more if you have bigger arrays). Then the compiler won't complain.